# Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found: - android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout (Fix Build Path, Create Class)

Tags: android, xml

I learn material design with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tR2K_Sav7q8

and I get this error :

[image: MyError]

A Part of **build.gradle** :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

And **activity_main.xml** :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#363537"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.materialdesign.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: did you figure out the solution for this? struggling to make it work for weeks.

Comment: Yes,I have update my android studio 1.2.2 to 1.3(in beta channel) for this go in Help->Check Update->See the updates dialog.